# Not able to write a proper code to automate the registration form

Tags: testing, automated-tests

to automate the registration form so that i have not to enter manually all the time

from selenium import web driver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium. web driver. support .ui import WebDriver Wait
from selenium. web driver. support import expected_ conditions as EC
from selenium. web driver. common. keys import Keys

driver = web driver. Chrome(executable_ path='PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER')

```
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
wait = Web Driver Wait(driver, 10)
wait. until(EC. presence_ of_ element_ located((By. TAG_NAME, 'app-root')))
input_ field = driver. find_ element_ by_ css_ selector('input[type="text"]') 
input_ field. send_ keys('Test data') 
submit_ button = driver. find_ element_ by _css_ selector('button[type="submit"]') 
submit_ button. click()
dynamic_ element = wait. until(EC. presence_ of_ element_ located((By. XPATH, '//div[@class="dynamic-element"]'))) 


dynamic_ element. click()
```

except Exception as e:
print("An error occurred:", e)

finally:

```
driver. quit()
```

Comment: Are all those weird spacing issues in your actual code? `dynamic_ element. click()` etc.